# Variational principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, variational-principle

In the [LMTO method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muffin-tin_approximation), the interstitial region is approximated by plane waves and the muffin tin region of the potential by solutions to the radial Schrodinger equation.
In using the variational method for calculating the ground state energy a linear combination of the two solutions is used.

The Hamiltonian consists of $V_0$ (interstitial), $V_1$ (muffin tin-spherical part and the kinetic energy term) and $V_2$ (muffin tin non spherical part).

Now how do these various parts act on the linear combination of wavefunctions? Will they act separately as in $V_0$ (interstitial) acts only on the plane waves?